# Increasing UILabel.text from a number to a specified number in a specified duration time?

Tags: swift, timer, queue

I want to increment a lable's text(which is number) with animation, so user can see the number increase one by one, for this case i used a for loop.
the total amount of the loop can be 10 or a big number(e.g. 1234567889).
i want the loop always executes in a sepecific period(e.g 2 seconds).
whether the totalAmount is 10 or 1234567889.
does anybody know how to do that?

```
let totalAmount = 200
for i in 0...totalAmount {
    label.text = String(describing: i)
}
```

one solution is using a **timer** ,
another is generating **pauses** during above loop in a **queue**, 
But these didn't help me to get the expected result. these requires some complicated calculations which I couldn't reach. If you also have any idea about these solutions let me know.

to be exact, I am thinking about finding a solution like animating the value of the label from startValue to endValue in a specific duration time. like `UIView.animateWithduration` or `CABasicAnimation`. But I couldn't find animation for the **value** of a label.

Comment: I'd suggest to check [UICountingLabel](https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel) library

Comment: That's good, thanks @AhmadF